# .NET GC of unreferenced objects with static members

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, finalizer

So I'm curious, will GC - and especially finalization - occur on an instance `x` in .NET when:

- `x` is not referenced by anything
- `x` has a static `DbConnection` property
- `y` is an instance of the same class as `x`
- `y` is still referenced by something

It strikes me that in this event, `x` could be declared dead by external references - but executing finalization on it may cause the `DbConnection` to be disposed while `y` still needs and holds a reference to it.

So which is it, in the scenario I described, is `x` collected? Does it get finalized? Or do all instances of it's type need to orphan in the heap before any one of them is collected? Will finalization happen across each instance?

I would think so, is the general rule to be followed just: Never touch a static or otherwise shared object in your finalizers?

Comment: For completeness you should propably add that the type defines a finalizer. Otherwise instances will never be eligible for finalization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `x` instance would be eligible for GC.  The `DbConnection`, since it is static, is completely unrelated to the instances in this case, and not relevant for determining whether the object is eligible for GC.  It will not get collected as long as the static property holds a reference.

> Never touch a static or otherwise shared object in your finalizers?

This is typically a good call.  In general, you should never write finalizers for your managed types, unless they're wrapping unmanaged resources, at which point the type should do nothing but manage that resource (ideally).  Even then, using `SafeHandle` is often a better approach when possible.

Comment: your last sentence sounds like it contradicts everything else you're saying.... ? I must be reading it wrong?

Comment: Do expand on your comment about `SafeHandle` if possible - I'm unfamiliar with alternative approaches to serving the safety purpose finalizers do - knowing they cause pinning is enough to make me want to avoid them to begin with if possible...

Comment: @JimmyHoffa In general, a class with a finalizer should do nothing but manage the native resource.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.100).ASPX for more details on SafeHandle, but for Win32 resources, that's typically the best approach.

Comment: I know a finalizer should only manage the native resource, but in the event that said native resource is static, knowing statics are supposed to be process scoped, and they'll be cleaned up at process exit so... I guess it makes sense to let unmanaged static resources just live until process end.. I still don't know what you're encouraging one to do with `SafeHandle`.. inherit from it *instead* of adding a finalizer?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Yes - and I would never have a native resource in a static.  Worst case, if you really need it, make it a singleton of an object with the finalizer so that it has normal finalization behavior...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60117/discussion-between-jimmy-hoffa-and-reed-copsey).